# Change values in a list to those specified in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list containing tuples with pairs, the first element is a name (string), the second is a list containing the restaurants that person has been to.
I have a dict containing the scores of such restaurants. Therefore, if person A has been to restaurants `(x,y,z)` therefore, `[('A', ['x', 'y', 'z'])]`and my dict states that `{'x':10, 'y':23, 'z':33}`. How can I replace the names of the restaurants to the numbers specified in the dictionary containing the names?
Having the output `[('A', [10, 23, 33])]`.
After that, I want to sum those numbers up having `[('A', [66])]`.

Thank you.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
restaurants_attended = [('Aariz Lambert', ['The Beach Chimney', 'Parlay', 'The Private Exhibit']), ('Ariya Collier', ['Seawise', 'Enigma', 'Midnight'])]
```

```
{'The Beach Chimney': 201.0, "The Pirate's Harvest": 154.0, 'The Square Dragon': 132.0, 'The Spicy Trumpet': 266.0, 'Vertigo': 204.0, 'Drifters': 183.0, 'The Tulip': 156.0, 'Seawise': 136.0, 'Parlay': 140.0, 'The Modern Salmon': 176.0, 'The Bitter Windmill': 139.0, 'The Minty Window': 166.0, 'The Private Exhibit': 189.0, 'Enigma': 228.0, 'The Lighthouse': 159.0, 'Harlequin': 131.0, 'Midnight': 141.0, 'Gastrognome': 166.0}
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Have you actually tried doing any of this? The code you are using is just the data. You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I've been trying it for a while, but I just can't get it to work. If I go through the whole code it would be pretty long, that's just the final step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
restaurants_attended = [('Aariz Lambert', ['The Beach Chimney', 'Parlay', 'The Private Exhibit']), ('Ariya Collier', ['Seawise', 'Enigma', 'Midnight'])]
scores = {'The Beach Chimney': 201.0, "The Pirate's Harvest": 154.0, 'The Square Dragon': 132.0, 'The Spicy Trumpet': 266.0, 'Vertigo': 204.0, 'Drifters': 183.0, 'The Tulip': 156.0, 'Seawise': 136.0, 'Parlay': 140.0, 'The Modern Salmon': 176.0, 'The Bitter Windmill': 139.0, 'The Minty Window': 166.0, 'The Private Exhibit': 189.0, 'Enigma': 228.0, 'The Lighthouse': 159.0, 'Harlequin': 131.0, 'Midnight': 141.0, 'Gastrognome': 166.0}

output = {person: [scores[r] for r in rests] for person, rests in restaurants_attended}
print(output) # {'Aariz Lambert': [201.0, 140.0, 189.0], 'Ariya Collier': [136.0, 228.0, 141.0]}
output_sum = {person: sum(scores) for person, scores in output.items()}
print(output_sum) # {'Aariz Lambert': 530.0, 'Ariya Collier': 505.0}
```

If you want lists of tuples, as you specified, use `list` like in:

```py
print(list(output.items())) # [('Aariz Lambert', [201.0, 140.0, 189.0]), ('Ariya Collier', [136.0, 228.0, 141.0])]
```